# Use typing.Literal in dataclass reader

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses, csvreader

I have a csv file that I'd like to process to a dataclass. I'd like to check that the grades in my dataset are only from a prespecified list, if this is not the case I'd like to log an error/warning. My class looks as follows

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Literal

grade_options = Literal['1A', '1B', '1C']

class Student:
    name: str
    age: int
    grade: grade_options
```

I read my csv file (using the `dataclass-csv` [library](https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-csv/)), yet it has problems to instantiate this type

```
from dataclass_csv import DataclassReader

with open('students.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig") as read_csv:
    reader = DataclassReader(read_csv, Student, delimiter=";")
    students = [student for student in reader]
```

This will result in a `TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Literal`

Is there any other option than creating a manual checker to see if my values in the csv file are one of the specified options?

Comment: Its a good idea.. certainly, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. You have to use concrete classes that extend `Enum`.

Based on ["Create an enum class" in the tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class):

```py
from enum import Enum


class Grade(str, Enum):
    _1a: '1A'
    _1b: '1B'
    _1c: '1C'

class Student:
    name: str
    age: int
    grade: Grade
```